# Azure Function Binding Expression for Function Name

Tags: azure-functions

Is there a binding expression that says what the function name is with an HTTP input binding? I've tried {functionname}, {methodname}, {triggermetadata.methodname} and I can't figure it out.

I want to use the same function name to associate the function to a table output binding with the same name as the function, but there's no documentation of the http metadata binding expressions.

A workaround is to make my route "/api/{FunctionName}" and then I can use {functionname} but that has issues in and of itself, is there a native expression binding instead?

Comment: the *FunctionName* is a property of the **ExecutingContext** and it can be obtained within the function code.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I want to use it as a binding expression in an output binding.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, in a bit of a roundabout way: {sys.methodname} works